# why hadoop lost nodes

Tags: hadoop, nodes

I am confused that when I run the commond " hadoop dfsadmin -report" I can see there

[image]

but the resource manager , cluster metric, it shows that

[image]

why is that and why could that happen?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connected with 9 slave nodes. But 5 slave nodes are in active state remaining are in unhealthy state.

**Reason for unhealthy state:**

Hadoop MapReduce provides a mechanism by which administrators can configure the TaskTracker to run an administrator supplied script periodically to determine if a node is healthy or not. Administrators can determine if the node is in a **healthy state** by performing any checks of their choice in the script. If the script detects the node to be in an unhealthy state, it must print a line to standard output beginning with the string ERROR. The TaskTracker spawns the script periodically and checks its output. If the script's output contains the string ERROR, as described above, the node's status is reported as **'unhealthy'** and the node is black-listed on the JobTracker. No further tasks will be assigned to this node. However, the TaskTracker continues to run the script, so that if the node becomes healthy again, it will be removed from the blacklisted nodes on the JobTracker automatically. The node's health along with the output of the script, if it is unhealthy, is available to the administrator in the JobTracker's web interface. The time since the node was healthy is also displayed on the web interface.

**Reason for Lost Nodes:**

I think some BLOCKS (data) may not available in  slaves. So It shows lost node as 9.

To **remove Dead nodes** from cluster use this link [To Decommission Nodes](http://maheshwaranm.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-decommission-nodes.html)

Comment: Updated steps to decommission nodes, let me know if you have any doubts, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cluster metrics in ResourceManager show the status of NodeManager.

`hadoop dfsadmin -report` this command shows the status of Datanodes.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the relation of  'active nodes' and 'lost nodes' ,because I have only 9 datanodes, why it said 'active nodes is 5' but 'lost nodes is 8', 5+8 =13 >9